# String Date conversion into sql date format MM/dd/yyyy?

Tags: java, sql, date, ms-access, jdbc

```
public void setEmployeeDetails(String month,String year,String day) throws

SQLException, ParseException
{

        String sql="INSERT INTO EmployeeDetails (SiteName,EmployeeName,EmployeePhoneNumber,Date) VALUES(?,?,?,?)"; 
          pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql) ;

             String date=month+"/"+day+"/"+year;
             SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
             java.util.Date parsed = format.parse(date);
             java.sql.Date sql_date = new java.sql.Date(parsed.getTime());
             System.out.println(sql_date);
         }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, ParseException{
        Employee_Details_DAO e=new Employee_Details_DAO();
        e.setEmployeeDetails("12","2006","10");
    }
```

I want to convert string date as format MM/ddd/yyy to sql ms access date format. But I got the  output as 2006-12-10 but output should be as 12/10/2006

Comment: this code gives `MM/ddd/yyy` format only.

Comment: nopes, it gives yyyy-MM-ddd format as mentioned above 2006-12-10

Comment: I think you need a formatter for the sql_date variable.  Or even better get rid of sql_date.  Not sure why you're creating an instance of java.util.Date to create an instance of java.sql.Date.  And you'll want to format it AFTER creating the instance, not before.

Comment: `java.sql.Date`'s `toString()` method always outputs dates in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. Unsure what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `System.out.println(sql_date);` is displaying the date value as `2006-12-10` it is because it is using a *default* `yyyy-mm-dd` format, either from Java or from the operating system. It doesn't mean that the date is "wrong", it is just being displayed in a different way.

Always remember:

**Date *values* do NOT have formats.** They are just (numeric) values that correspond to a particular date.

***[String] Representations* of Dates *do* have a format.** However, the *format* does not affect the *value* in any way. Whether it's `2006-12-25` or `12/25/2006` or `December 25, 2006` or `2006 décembre 25` the Date *value* is still the same.

So, you don't need to worry about using any particular *format* for a Date parameter, just pass the value itself:

```java
try (
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connStr);
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO EmployeeDetails ([Date]) VALUES (?)")) {
    String month = "12";   //
    String year = "2006";  // sample data
    String day = "10";     //
    ps.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(year + "-" + month + "-" + day));
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.out.println(format.format(sql_date));//12/10/2006
```

`java.sql.Date` is a sub-class of `java.util.Date`. So we can format for `java.sql.Date` same as `java.util.Date`.